# whats the best way to handle multiple database calls in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, callback

I have a node app hitting postgres, in one of my functions I will need to be able to query many tables to get data to assemble for my json to send back. What is the best way to do this given the nature of nodejs, and I would like to avoid multiple levels of nested callbacks? I have been hunting around, but just am not grokking this concept well.

Comment: Perfectly explained in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6604036/1520671

Comment: have you tried wait.for? https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your queries nature, if you need them execute one after another, or in parallel, gathering all the results/errors in one place.

Typical approach to avoid nested callback hell is to use [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) library (and [series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback), [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) functions) or it's analogs.

It would be something like this:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        db.query(..., callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
        db.query(..., callback);
    }
],

function(err, results) {
    // results is array containing array of results of your queries
});
```

Please refer to [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) documentation for more info and examples.