# How do you pass sync query’s to SQL Server in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, synchronization, electron

I have found plenty of info on async queries for SQL Server, but I can't find anything on synchronous. The app was much simpler and ran much smoother when I was using MySQL and could perform sync queries. However it is required that I switch to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

So there is nothing wrong in your use case to use nested callback program structure in node js to achieve sync queries. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597493/synchronous-database-queries-with-node-js) answer clearly shows that nesting callbacks depending on the use case doesn't end up in the bad category

Comment: The answer you are referring to is for MySql. I am asking about MSSQL. Passing sync query in MySql is easy.