# mysql query wont push values to array

Tags: mysql, node.js

trying to gather some titles from my roles table and put them into an array so i can loop over them later but when i run the function it doesn't give me a array with the values I'm guessing

```
function setRoles() {
    let roleSet = [];

    let sql = "SELECT * FROM role";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            roleSet.push(res[i]);

        }



    });
    console.log(roleSet);
    return roleSet;

}
```

here is the code the only thing i get back is a empty array and ive tried putting the array init outside the function and that doesnt work either

Comment: Simply, replace `console.log` and `return` statement in `connection.query`. You can make `connection.query` as `async` function and get with `await`.

Comment: i change it and i get a promise pending ?

Comment: Yes. In my case, I use `async` module.

Answer (score 1):

How about change `console.log` after query?
It maybe not return anything.

You can change `setRoles` function as async, but I can't make `async/await` code perfectly.

So, I reference another module(`async`) for use `mysql`.

```js
function setRoles() {
    let roleSet = [];

    let sql = "SELECT * FROM role";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            roleSet.push(res[i]);
        }
        console.log(roleSet);
        //return roleSet;
    });
    //console.log(roleSet);
    //return roleSet;
}
```

```js
connection.query('SELECT * FROM some_table', (err, rows) => {
    // do something with the results here
});
// the following code is executed *before* the query is executed
```

I reference [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6604036/10357400) code.